# How to obtain information on tensorflow architecture

Tags: python, architecture, tensorflow

I have been working on retraining TensorFlow Inception v3 (see [TensorFlow Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception)) and was curious as to how I would obtain some general "metadata" about the model.

For instance:

- How many hidden layers are there?
- Which is the "last" layer that gets retrained?
- How many total neurons (or neurons / layer)?
- How many convolutions were used?
- How many poolings were used?

I basically want to be able to write a sentence or two describing the model. There is sentence on the site

> ...single frame evaluation with a computational cost of 5 billion multiply-adds per inference and with using less than 25 million parameters.

but I am not quit sure what that means.  Is that 25 million neurons?

Looking at the document [Rethinking the Inception Architecture for Computer Vision](http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.00567) which was referenced on the GitHub, I think much of what I need is in Table 1?

Would I write this ?

"TensorFlow InceptionV3 is a deep convolution neural network that has 13 hidden layers and uses six convolutions, two pooling steps, and three inception modules to perform a softmax classification of images"

Of course I want the correct data in the sentence and would love to know how many neurons are in the model as well

Thanks!

[image: Table 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very much on the right track.  Yes, parameters are neurons.  For instance, the output of the first conv layer is 32 filters (kernels) of grid size 149^2.  That's a total of 710,432 neurons/parameters for that layer alone.

The critical part of training is back-propagation which adjusts the weights between one layer and the next.  The result of that SoftMax operation is the 1000 output predictions; the last trained layer would be its connection to the prior layer.

You can read the simple convolutions and poolings from the chart.  I'm not sure whether or not you are supposed to include the ones inside the inception layers.

Finally, if I read this correctly, the inceptions are multiple units of each type, applied in series.  That would mean that we have 10 inception layers, not 3.